Unexpected token - when uploading app to iOS store
I'm using fastlane to upload the app to the iOS store. The only error that I get is the exception unexpected token at '' -
It is the same error for both app store and test flight fastlane commands
      upload_to_app_store( api_key_path: APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY_PATH, precheck_include_in_app_purchases: false, app_identifier: IOS_PRODUCTION_APP_STORE_BUNDLE_ID, metadata_path: './metadata/ios/app', metadata: metadata, screenshots: screenshots, force: true, phased_release: true, app_version_update: true )
      upload_to_testflight( api_key_path: APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY_PATH, demo_account_required: true, app_identifier: IOS_PRODUCTION_APP_STORE_BUNDLE_ID, ipa: ipa_directory, waiting_for_build_processing: true, distribute_external: true, changelog: "Review our new App.", beta_app_review_info: { contact_email: ENV['IOS_CONTACT_EMAIL'], contact_first_name: ENV['IOS_CONTACT_NAME'], contact_last_name: ENV['IOS_CONTACT_LAST_NAME'], contact_phone: ENV['IOS_CONTACT_NUMBER'], demo_account_name: ENV['IOS_CONTACT_DEMO_ACCOUNT_LOGIN'], demo_account_password: ENV['IOS_CONTACT_DEMO_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD'], notes: "thank you for reviewing our App" } )
Due the lack of information about the error, I haven't tried anything yet. This code is in the master branch. I wonder if the ipa file was created correctly or the fastlane command is not finding the path automatic as the doc says it should.
